# Why are balloontips delayed when the screen is locked?

Tags: .net, winforms, balloon-tip

An application I've written displays a balloon tip (using [`NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) when a certain event happens. This can also happen while the system is locked.

In this case the balloon tip does not immediatels display after unlocking it or not at all - both cases would be fine and make sense. However, it displays after some time - sometimes more than half an hour.

This behaviour is very annoying and I'd like to know if there's a way to prevent it except checking if the screen is locked before showing the balloontip.

Comment: That's novel.  It has to be environmental.  Try it on another machine.  This belongs at superuser.com btw.

Comment: How is this something for superuser.com? I have this issue especially with balloontips created by my application. So it might be related to the method I'm using. Additionally the solution is most likely programming-related, too...

Comment: Because it is environmental.  If you believe that it is related to the way you show the tips then you should have posted a code snippet to help us reproduce the behavior.  That would have made it a  programming question.

Comment: I did mention the function. Since it's extremely simple it's not really necessary to post a snipped which does nothing but call that function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Taskbar notifications** (this is the official terminology) have tricky logic associated with them.

1. **Notifications are displayed either immediately, or after resuming from certain states**, such as when the PC is locked (or playing a fullscreen game):

   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/10/349894.aspx
2. In Vista and later, notifications are only **displayed for 9 seconds**, and this is not adjustable:

   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/18/10165605.aspx
3. **Notification balloons do not show up at all for the first hour a user is logged on** for the first time:

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx

Most importantly, Windows does not guarantee that the user will see them.  In the [**Windows UX Guidelines**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511497.aspx), they state:

> **Don't assume that users will see your notifications**. Users won't see
>   them when:
>
> - They are immersed in their work.
> - They aren't paying attention.
> - They away from their computer.
> - They are running a full-screen application.
> - Their administrator has turned off all notifications for their computer.

It also states that the user might not see the messages in time either, in which case you should **unqueue your messages when they are no longer relevant**.  You can do this by calling `ShowBalloonTip(0, String.Empty, String.Empty, ToolTipIcon.None)`.  I think doing this is your best bet to prevent irrelevant balloons from being shown.